# Is there a way to fix safari from creating grid lines when scaling or transforming an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

In safari, when I transform/scale an iframe, I get some weird grid lines that appear and disappear. How can I remove them?

Here is a codepen, make sure you shrink or increase your viewport to see them.
https://codepen.io/davidsalazar/full/yLxxNQX

```
<iframe class="position-absolute" style="transform: scale(.7);" scrolling="no" src="https://flysumo.com/davidksalazar">
</iframe>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm referring to.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:
`#result { will-change: transform, filter; }`
or
`#result * { will-change: transform, filter; }`